# Create Word Doc

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have generated

[image]

[image: Directory]

How would I create a Word Document from the source with C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DOCX` file is just a zip file with a different extension. If you have the contents correct, you can zip up the files using classes from the System.IO.Compression namespace.  Look at the examples provided for the [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) class.